# Need help in scraping list of hotel from a website with fixed urls and dynamically loading the content?

Tags: python, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the details from a hotel listing site [this site](http://dineout.co.in/bangalore-restaurants?search_str=).
Here when we click the next button for the next page the url remain the same and when looked with inspect element there site is sending a XHR request. I tried to use selenium webdriver and python and the following is my code

```
from time import sleep
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

class DineoutRestaurantSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dineout_restaurant'
    allowed_domains = ['dineout.co.in/bangalore-restaurants?search_str=']
    start_urls = ['http://dineout.co.in/bangalore-restaurants?search_str=']
    def start_requests(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/macbookpro/Downloads/chromedriver')
        self.driver.get('https://www.dineout.co.in/bangalore-restaurants?search_str=')'

url = 'https://www.dineout.co.in/bangalore-restaurants?search_str='
**yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)**
self.logger.info('Empty message')

for i in range(1, 4):
    try:
        next_page = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[text()="Next "]')
        sleep(11)
        self.logger.info('Sleeping for 11 seconds.')
        next_page.click()
        url = 'https://www.dineout.co.in/bangalore-restaurants?search_str='
        yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)

    except NoSuchElementException:
        self.logger.info('No more pages to load.')
        self.driver.quit()
        break

def parse(self, response):
self.logger.info('Entered parse method')
restaurants = response.xpath('//*[@class="cardBg"]')
for restaurant in restaurants:
     name = restaurant.xpath('.//*[@class="titleDiv"]/h4/a/text()').extract_first()
     location = restaurant.xpath('.//*[@class="location"]/a/text()').extract()
     rating = restaurant.xpath('.//*[@class="rating rating-5"]/a/span/text()').extract_first()
     yield{
            'Name': name,
            'Location': location,
            'Rating': rating,
            }`
```

In the above code the yield Request doesnot goto the parse function? Am I  missing anything?I am not getting any error But the scrape output is only of the 1st page even though the pages are being iterated

Comment: `**yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)**` this is a comment right?